# MySQL: Get not included dates from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Please refer to this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a9c0/4). In that table, there is missing data from `2014-09-21` to `2014-09-30`.

The second sql is what I wanted. If there are no differences between  allotments the result is ok. But with the difference, I want `0` as the output. Coz there are dates that not having allotments.

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: you want like this SELECT room_id, from_date, to_date from room_allotment WHERE (('2014-09-05' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date) || ('2014-10-05' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date)
);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all who pay attention for my question. For now it seems like there is no a better solution (data base side). So i'm doing it in PHP side by looping through dates and checking the db for the specific date. I think it won't be big performance issue because normally the date range is a small one.

According to the question, this is not the answer. But i'll mark it as the answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT room_id, from_date, to_date, MIN(rooms) rooms FROM(

SELECT DISTINCT room_id, from_date, to_date, SUM(IFNULL(rooms,0)) rooms 
FROM room_allotment 
WHERE (from_date BETWEEN '2014-09-21' AND '2014-09-29'  and
     to_date BETWEEN '2014-09-21' AND '2014-09-29' ) AND room_id = '1'
GROUP BY room_id 
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT room_id, from_date, to_date, SUM(IFNULL(rooms,0)) rooms 
FROM room_allotment 
WHERE (from_date BETWEEN '2014-09-21' AND '2014-09-29'  and
     to_date BETWEEN '2014-09-21' AND '2014-09-29' ) AND room_id = '1'
GROUP BY room_id
)r
GROUP BY room_id
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a9c0/14)

Comment: Thanks @Sathish. But in your sql, you are just selecting data that doesn't exist. In my situation, i'm selecting data `BETWEEN 2014-09-15 AND 2014-10-05`. But I don't know weather there are data available for `2014-09-21 TO 2014-09-30`. In such a situation, I need `zero` as the result.